# Best Solution to load a big file to Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a text file with 457379 lines and this structure

```
Key1\t\tValue1
Key2\t\tValue2
```

I'm using this code to load it into a `Dictionary<string,string>`

```
private void StartScan()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("fh.txt"))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            scaned++;
            label4.Text = scaned.ToString();
            var read = sr.ReadLine().Split(new string[] { "\t\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            fh.Add(read[0], read[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

but it takes more than 6 minutes to load data.

The question is is there any better solution to load the data?

Comment: Do you need all of the data in memory at once? This question cannot be answered without knowing how you're going to be using it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It contains the md5 hash of alot of files and I need to find the files with same hash. (Duplicate files)

Comment: Could you perhaps use a database rather than a flat file? Any database would be more than happy to return matching rows, etc

Comment: It seems you're updating the label4 at each line. This can probably slow down the operation... you could try to update the label once every 20-100 line...

Comment: I'd guess you could read a bunch of lines and doing the parsing of those bunches asynchronously. But it's indeed hard to guess with the limited information,this might also be serious overkill.

Comment: @digEmAll since I'm running the function in another thread I don't think it takes too much time. but I'll check that too.

Comment: Refering to @digEmAll. Comment out the line `label4.Text = scaned.ToString();`. It could improve performance quite a bit.

Comment: @MarcGravell Database is good solution but the data is in file and It may change later so I can't convert it to database

Comment: @digEmAll It worked! it took only 2 seconds! answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're updating an UI element (`label4`) every time you read a line.

This can be very expensive, so either I suggest to remove the line:

```
label4.Text = scaned.ToString();
```

or update it less frequently, e.g. once every 100 lines read.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    private void StartScan()
    {
       var lastupdate = 0;

       ...

       if(lastUpdate + 100 < scaned) 
       { 
          label4.Text = scaned.ToString();
          lastUpdate = scaned;
       }
       ...
```

it might improve quite a bit...I guess the label updating is one of the most expensive operations in your code

Answer (score 0):

I find `File.ReadLines` to be the easiest/quickest way to process files line-by-line:

```
var dictionary = File.ReadLines("C:\\file.txt")
                     .Select(s => s.Split(new string[] { "\t\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
                     .ToDictionary(k => k[0], v => v[1]);
```

Having said that, there's not much functional difference between the code above and what you already have other than the fact it's slightly less verbose.

Comment: Thanks! since I hadn't measure the time with the old function I'm gonna measure that first then your code.

Comment: There's not much to choose between `StreamReader.ReadLine` and `File.ReadLines`. Neither is significantly faster, and both are streaming.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, I covered that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is use a bufferstream.

```
 using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
 using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
     {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //Do the add
        }
     }
```

You will see an improvement. Also do you need a Dictionary? If you don't need a key mapping to each value use a HashSet. It is slightly faster in adding. Just a bit but it might make a difference in the long run.